# WCF Soap Service call without waiting to finish

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I have a webservice which I want to call from a client tool (C#).
The challange is to call the webservice, without waiting for it to end.

An asnyc call will result in killing the webservice instance / resulting the call not to end.

I can **not** use Threads or Task to call the webservice in the client on an async process.

Is there some other way to not wait for a webservice to end?
If needed, I don't need a callback from the webservice.

Comment: *I can not use Threads or Task* - I really do not understand this statement, how would you execute something in the same thread without waiting for it to finish?

Comment: How does using async cause the webservice to crash?

Comment: I need a way to call it, without expecting an answer or to exit the webservice befor it ended. The initial problem is, that the function in the webservice will maybe run for 30-40 minutes. So I don't want the client to wait for it to end.

Comment: @BugFinder - the client side operation should end, befor the webservice is ended. So the process, where the asnyc operation on the client is started, will be ended and will result in an abroad on the webservice.

Comment: If you use task, the clr decide for you if to create new thread or not. Why async will kill your webservice? What is kill ? How is the web service configured? Read and understand, e.g https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/86007/3-ways-to-do-WCF-instance-management-Per-call-Per

Comment: Maybe the Webservice is just wrong. It should save the querry, and say to the client ok it's the querry # 235. And stop there. The web service could just be registering the call.

Comment: I believe your issue is in the Web Service: there is nearly no good reason to run a web service *call* for 30/40 minutes as a **synchronous** operation. You should really use a different pattern (e.g. a queue on the server and a service which will read and execute operations based on the queue contents)

Comment: @FedericoDipuma - I know your concern, but the webservice can not use the windows event message queue

Comment: @DragandDrop - what would be your go-to way to do this. 
How can I store / register in the webservice a query to later "work on this"? In my eyes I need a secondary application to this.

Comment: I wasn't talking about Windows Event Messages Queue or any other specific implementation, I was talking about the **pattern**. You current approach is both inefficient and problematic (beacause you rised the problem yourself). The queue pattern may be implemented in any way you like. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087826/what-is-the-correct-way-to-handle-long-running-service-operations-with-wcf-hoste) may help you further.

Comment: Imo, just change the pattern. It's not a bad thing. "In my eyes I need a secondary application to this", How is this a bad thing? Imagine your WebService as a FastFood Drive by. One take the order and give you the information you will need to pay. At the same time the order is in the process queue. The other way where the one taking your order is the one that process it is a bad idea..