# WCF. Long operations. Right approach

Tags: .net, wcf

One of the operations on WCF server is working about 8(!!!) hours... 
and I need to show result of this operation on the client when it is done.

Is it okay to hold a connection with client for so long time? 
If yes, will it be okay in case of 24hour-operation? 
Or it is better to use smth like
  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400263/wcf-windows-service-long-operations-callback-to-calling-module) ?

I tried to find the answer on SO, but wasn't successed..

Answer (score 2):

It is always much better to go asynchronous when dealing with operations that are expected to take considerable time (my personal rule of thumb for declaring an operation "slow running" is that the operation needs to take roughly the time required for an average user to hit "Reload" on a slow web page, which I guesstimate is about ten seconds; I worked for a company where any operation taking more than half a second was declared "slow").

Numerous issues exist with holding the connection open:

- **Timeouts** -  you would have to set them at eight hours, which is equivalent to disabling them for all practical purposes, at least as far as user interaction is concerned
- **Client restarts** - If your clients are holding on for a synchronous response from the server, reporting the results would not survive a restart of the client
- **Intermediate progress reports** - When an operation runs for several hours, it is likely that it consists of multiple stages. Going asynchronous lets you report on the percentage complete and on the operation process in general, as your operation goes through its multiple stages.

That is why you should strongly prefer using duplex communications for all your long-running operations.

Comment: Thanks for answer. 
I understand that there is duplex communication for such purposes. And my operation is async. 
But I want to know, is it okay to operation lasts 8 hours and client hold the a duplex connection with server all the time? 

Or should I use another mechanisms?

The link in my question gives a answer why I asked about it.