# WCF Exceptions with extreme impact on app performance

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.forms, uwp, .net-standard

I have an Xamarin.Forms app on .NET Standard 1.4 that uses WCF to communicate with a service that is located in the local network. As there are some very long running operations i had to implement very high timeouts (600 seconds). In case the service is unavailable the app would now sit there for 600 seconds and do nothing, just to tell the user, that the service is unavailable. So I implemented a ping contract, which calls a function ping every 5 seconds, so I know that the server is available, which is shown to the user (as requested by the user).

On Android this is fine. If the server is available, everything runs smoothly, and if the server is offline for some reason an exception is thrown, caught, and the user is notified that the server is offline.

On UWP on the other hand the Exception seems to be caught and re-thrown up a hundred times with a debug output through all the layers of the WCF Implementation before I can catch it. On my Lumia 930 this takes up to 9 seconds and is heavily impacting the device even when the whole ping operation is executed in a separate task which is not being awaited. In Release mode this is less extreme but still freezes up the UI most of the time. How can I get around this issue?

Edit:
This is printed **line by line**, not as **one block** every time a ping should be executed, but the service is unavailable. Also I'm not printing anything myself.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileLoadException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.ServiceModel.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Net.Http.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Private.ServiceModel.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Private.ServiceModel.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Reflection.DispatchProxy.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
```

Edit2:
I've updated every NuGet package in the project now (mainly `System.Net`, `System.ServiceModel` and the `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` packages) and it got a bit better. Before it would throw exceptions no matter the status of the service. Now it only throws exceptions when the service is unavailable, and there are less Exceptions:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.Threading.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.ServiceModel.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Net.Http.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Private.ServiceModel.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Private.ServiceModel.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.TimeoutException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

But the exceptions still freeze the GUI or any other tasks that are happening at that point.

Comment: `On UWP on the other hand the Exception seems to be caught and re-thrown up a hundred times with a debug output through all the layers of the WCF Implementation before I can catch it.` How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: Another edit with further information

Comment: Okay, when I run the app without the debugger, everything seems to be just fine. No freeze, no stutter, everything is just smooth as butter.

Comment: Consider a more sustainable approach to long-running operations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400263/wcf-windows-service-long-operations-callback-to-calling-module

Comment: Sadly the link in the accepted answer is dead, but as I'm limited to `BasicHttpBinding` I cannot use the MSMQ. Otherwise the queue aproach that is mentioned there seems quite interesting. I will test this as soon as I am able to which is sometime later this year at the earliest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same question as you and get the answer from this [post](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/11328). It may help for your information.

"What you are seeing is basically a Visual Studio debugger feature - any exception being thrown in the application is noticed by VS as a "first-chance exception".
See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/01/07/understanding-exceptions-while-debugging-with-visual-studio/.
When you run the app stand-alone without VS, you won't see these messages being printed.

A bit more detail: These exceptions are actually being thrown in the code as part of https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/11021/files, but they are expected & handled properly. It's really just a VS feature that they get printed."

Comment: Thank you for this information. Good to know that Visual Studio "just does it's job" but it should be a bit faster at it. Taking up seconds for exception handling even if it is in debugging only is not acceptable. But since that I've swiched to ASP.NET Core WebAPI and couldn't be more happy about it. It's faster, more flexible and easier to maintain than WCF. Also it works without pre-compiled proxy-class workarounds on iOS & UWP.